# Alter table query plan for sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to look for the query plan for alter table query in sql server management studio for sql server 2008.

the alter query is something like:

`alter table myTable add my_timestamp datetime not null default(getdate())`

When I try to see the 'estimated execution plan' for this query, it shows result as : 
Estimated Operator cost 0%. Also when I try to look for the 'actual execution plan' for the query, no result is shown. How can I see the query plan for this query?

Comment: Why do yo need query plan for it? Are you going to improve it? :)

Comment: What kind of action do you expect to see in the execution plan? A new (so far empty) column is added and nothing else should happen. Or did I miss something?

Comment: When a new column with a default value is inserted there must be something like an update query being fired for every row in the table. We can expect to see something in the query plan that confirms this.

Comment: You need to modify every row in your table and no other tables are accessed, so no optimization can be done, so what's the point of seeing the (presumably pretty simple) execution plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plan is not available for DDL statements, alas. I assume you want to know whether the statement will scan or update all rows, or whether it is just a metadata operation. The way to find that out is:

1. Read the docs
2. Test it

Answer (score 0):

The Display execution plan is valid only for Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements. The execution plan is not displayed for Data Definition Language (DDL) statements.

Your query is DDL. Hence the observed behaviour.

Raj

Comment: Using a query plan its easy to make out what database engine did while executing he query. Is it possible to see such a thing for a alter table query like the one I posted? Somewhere I found that sqlserver 2012 takes considerably less time as compared to sql server 2008 for such an alter table query. The difference could have been clear if something like a query plan could be seen.

Comment: @AnkitKumar - The reason for the difference [is explained here](http://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/online-non-null-with-values-column-add-in-sql-server-11/)